# How to define the type of elements in an rdf:Seq?

Tags: syntax, rdf, owl, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I want to create a property defining a `rdf:Seq` as a `rdfs:range` of an object :

```
eg:myProperty a rdf:Property;
    rdfs:range rdf:Seq;
    .
```

I'm looking for a way to define the type of the elements stored in the `rdf:Seq`. For example, I don't want this :

```
eg:typeOfElement a rdf:Class;
    .

eg:somethingElse a rdf:Class;
    .

[] eg:myProperty [
        a rdf:Seq;
        rdf:_1 [a eg:typeOfElement];   # It's the type I want
        rdf:_2 [a eg:typeOfElement];   # It's the type I want
        rdf:_3 [a eg:somethingElse];   # I don't want this type
    ];
    .
```

Is there a way to define that the `rdf:Seq` elements are only of the type of `eg:typeOfElement` when I define `eg:myProperty`?

(I can use owl if necessary.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably a number of ways to accomplish this, depending on your implementation preferences. My advice is to use the [`rdf:li`](http://smiy.sourceforge.net/olo/spec/orderedlistontology.html) special property in place of the arbitrary `rdf:_nnn`, which is easier to extend. `rdf:li` is equivalent to `rdf:_1`, `rdf:_2` in order. So the following code blocks are equivalent:

```
:mySeq a rdf:Seq;
  rdf:_1 :foo;
  rdf:_2 :bar .

:mySeq a rdf:Seq;
  rdf:li :foo;
  rdf:li :bar .
```

Note that the order in the second block is significant.

To accomplish what you are asking, you can extend `rdf:li` with a new property and refine its domain/range (although these are only really meaningful to human readers, as the child property inherits the semantics of the parent):

```
:myItem rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:li;
  rdfs:range :typeOfElement;
  rdfs:domain :mySeq .
```

`:myItem` inherits the semantics of `rdf:li`, so whatever implementatin logic you have can infer that the values of `:myItem` are in some meaningful order. Next define the `:mySeq` class via a property restriction:

```
:mySeq rdfs:subClassOf [ 
    a owl:Restriction; 
    owl:onProperty :myItem;
    owl:allValuesFrom :typeOfElement;].
```

which asserts that `:mySeq` is a class of all things where the property `:myItem` is explicitly used for values of `:typeOfElement`. You can now create lists with `:mySeq`.

---

To go a step further, you may define `:mySeq` as the intersection of the above rule and `rdf:Seq`:

```
:mySeq a owl:Class;
    owl:equivalentClass
    [ a owl:Class;
        owl:intersectionOf
          ( rdf:Seq
            [a owl:Restriction;
             owl:onProperty :myItem;
             owl:allValuesFrom :typeOfElement ]) ] .
```

Note the use `owl:equivalentClass` in place of `rdfs:subClassOf`. If we treat `owl:equivalentClass` as symmetric and subsumed by `rdfs:subClassOf`, eg:

```
owl:equivalentClass a owl:SymmetricProperty .
owl:equivalentClass rdfs:subPropertyOf rdfs:subClassOf .
```

then we can have equivalence that goes in both directions. Therefore all instances of `rdf:Seq` whose values for `:myItem` are of `:typeOfElement` are also instances of `:mySeq`. In this case you are inferring the type. So via the statement:

```
:x a rdf:Seq; :myItem :foo, :bar .
```

you may infer that `:x a :mySeq`.

Comment: It's only a part of the answer. I can't say which of the property, `rdf:_n` or `:myItem`, I will use in `:mySeq`. My principal problem is to force `:mySeq` to only use `:myItem`. So I think I will have to define a sub-class of `rdf:Seq` or something like that.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I've updated my answer. Hope it gets you on a better track. Also have a look at the [ordered list ontology](http://smiy.sourceforge.net/olo/spec/orderedlistontology.html), which may be easier to work with than the rdf containers.